# Ill-conditioned matrix problem: unexpected increase in eigenvalues for polynomial degree higher than 10

Tags: matrix, integration, eigenvalue

I am performing the buckling analysis of a beam with Ritz method. I have implemented the method in Python, and it calculates the eigenvalues of the stiffness matrix using the geometry matrix( the critical buckling loads). However, I have encountered an unexpected issue where the minimum positive eigenvalue starts increasing for a node count higher than 10, instead of converging to a constant value as expected.

```
Em = 70
Ec = 380
Pm = 2707
Pc = 3960
u = 0.3

# Thicknesses
h = 1
h0 = -0.5
h1 = -h / 4
h2 = h / 4
h3 = 0.5

# Volume, material properties, stiffness coefficient functions
def Vc(z, p):
    if h0 <= z <= h1:
        return ((z - h0) / (h1 - h0)) ** p
    elif h1 < z < h2:
        return 1
    elif h2 <= z <= h3:
        return ((z - h3) / (h2 - h3)) ** p
    else:
        return 0

def E(z, p):
    return Ec * Vc(z, p) + Em * (1 - Vc(z, p))

def A11(p):
    return integrate.quad(lambda z: E(z, p), -h / 2, h / 2)[0]

def B11(p):
    return integrate.quad(lambda z: E(z, p) * z, -h / 2, h / 2)[0]

def E11(p):
    return integrate.quad(lambda z: E(z, p) * z ** 2, -h / 2, h / 2)[0]


# Ritz method shape function for simple support beam
def U(x, i):
    return (x - L) * x ** i

def U1(x, i):
    return i * (x - L) * x ** (i - 1) + x ** i

def W(x, i):
    return (x - L) * x ** i

def W1(x, i):
    return i * (x - L) * x ** (i - 1) + x ** i

def W2(x, i):
    return 2 * i * x ** (i - 1) + i * (x - L) * (i - 1) * x ** (i - 2)

r = 6  # number of nodes
L = 5

# Initialize stiffness and geometry matrices
K11 = np.zeros((r, r))
K12 = np.zeros((r, r))
K22 = np.zeros((r, r))
N11 = np.zeros((r, r))
N22 = np.zeros((r, r))

p_list = [0, 1, 2, 5, 10]  # volume fraction indices

for p in p_list:
    for i in range(1, r + 1):
        for j in range(1, r + 1):
            K11[i - 1, j - 1] = A11(p) * integrate.quad(lambda x: U1(x, i) * U1(x, j), 0, L)[0]
            K12[i - 1, j - 1] = -B11(p) * integrate.quad(lambda x: U1(x, i) * W2(x, j), 0, L)[0]
            K22[i - 1, j - 1] = E11(p) * integrate.quad(lambda x: W2(x, i) * W2(x, j), 0, L)[0]
            N11[i - 1, j - 1] = B11(p) * integrate.quad(lambda x: U1(x, i) * W2(x, j), 0, L)[0]
            N22[i - 1, j - 1] = integrate.quad(lambda x: W1(x, i) * W1(x, j), 0, L)[0]

    K = np.block([[K11, K12], [K12, K22]])  # stiffness matrix
    N = np.block([[N11, N11], [N11, N22]])  # geometry matrix

    zz= linalg.eigvals(K, N)  # calculate eigenvalues
    positive_zz = [val for val in zz if val > 0]
    min_positive_zz = min(positive_zz)
    ncr = (12 * zz * L ** 2) / (Em * h ** 3)
    print(ncr)
```

I expected the minimum positive eigenvalue to decrease and converge to a constant value as I increase the number of nodes (r). However, contrary to expectations, it suddenly starts increasing for r higher than 10. I am seeking assistance in identifying and resolving the programming-related issues causing this behavior.